# Linux iproute2 default routing rules for IPv6

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6, route

I've been doing some tests with the ip commnand on Linux, and the "ip rule" command showed me different results for IPv4 and IPv6:

```
test-linux# ip -4 rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
test-linux# ip -6 rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
```

Is there a reason why the **"from all lookup default"** rule only appears in the IPv4 list? Is this rule somehow special that only works with IPv4?

I posted this question before on StackOverflow before, but it was closed due to not being related to programming. I've found some information about the iproute2 in this board, but if I'm mistaken again, could someone kindly redirect me to the correct board?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IPv6 learns its route from the RAs (Router Advertisements). For example, you do not configure a default gateway for IPv6, the RAs will define that.

Comment: You can add it if you like it: `ip -6 rule add pref 32767 lookup default`. This won't change anything to the system, just as it does nothing with IPv4 (until multiple routing tables are really used which implies probably more rules for adequate policy-based routing)